# Do my questions belong here, or in Movies & TV or in Anime & Manga?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted 2 questions over at Movies & TV regarding DVD releases of some cartoon robots and a cartoon super-hero, which might have been appropriate to ask here, but I was uncertain.  I [asked about where they should belong in Movies & TV Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/i-recently-asked-two-questions-specific-to-dvd-releases-do-they-belong-here-or) and didn't think it would harm anything to follow-up asking here as well, considering there might not be any participant overlap.

So... would said questions have been better here or there, or considering the robot cartoon was based on Japanese animation, in the anime group?

Comment: See also [How do we handle conflicts with the Anime and Movies sites?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/626)

Comment: Since it's regarding their releases on DVD, I think I picked the right site, at least for the super-hero one; the robots one might be better with the anime group considering the source material and the likelihood of expertise, but I didn't think to consider an anime group existed until I realized my question might be multi-suited.

Comment: Site scopes are not distinct sets, so when something falls under both just pick the one you feel is best suited.  Don't post to both, though, unless you can truly tailor the question in a meaningful way for each site.

Comment: Right. I don't plan to distribute the posts, and I didn't ask this over at the anime group meta.  I DID pretty much duplicate this meta post from TV over here, but primarily because I suspected (correctly) that this is a much more active meta than the TV & Movies meta.

Answer (score 13):

When there is an overlap between sites, the simple way to choose which site to ask on (it's *never* both) is by asking yourself who you want answers from.

In this case, do you want answers from experts on movie & TV in general, or answers from experts in the scifi/fantasy genre, or answers from experts in the Anime/Manga genre? Which of these groups is most likely to have the information you want? Which is likely to have wider knowledge that will make their answers most interesting to you?